# How do people make these animations?

Tags: animation

I've been looking at lots of the Motion Graphics on Behance lately and i'm wondering what program and how these people make these animations?

Some examples:
[image]
http://www.behance.net/gallery/Think-With-Google/11204911

http://www.behance.net/gallery/Vector-experiments/9710159

Any help would help a ton.  I'm sure lots other people would want this as well.

Comment: how do people make any animations, Adobe Flash?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - You could use Flash also, but this particular animation was done in After Effects. Not sure if Flash exports to Animated Gif or not.

Comment: from what i remember it does export to gif. But it doesn't have as many tools as after effects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## What Program?

Those "Think with Google" animations were made with **After Effects**.

One of the things I like about [Behance](http://www.behance.net) is if the author chooses to post the tools they used, it will show up in the right column under their name. The link you posted says it was made with After Effects & Illustrator CS6.

[image: Behance Tools used]

## How?

From what I've gathered from inquiring about these animations myself, the graphics are:

1. Created in `Illustrator`
2. Then imported into `After Effects` to create the animations.
3. Then exported as `animated GIFs`.

Comment: +1 You could also do that 100% in After Effects - it has its own set of vector tools.

Comment: After effects looks so complicated....i do wanna animate though.

Comment: It can be, but it can also be really simple if you want to do editing and less complex animations. [This will get you started on the basics](http://tv.adobe.com/show/learn-after-effects-cc/), just skip straight to the 'Essential tasks' section and you'll be working productively in AE in less than a couple of hours. @MuhammadUmer